# To Add Header and Footer for many word documents?

Tags: vba, header, ms-word, footer

I have around 100 documents for which the header and footer need to be changed.

Is there a possibility that i can do it just by writing a vba code or Macro in a word file?

Is it possible to give a specific folder in a macro which ll add the header and footer for all the documents in that footer?

the below code gives me

> error-5111

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

        Call openAllfilesInALocation

End Sub


Sub openAllfilesInALocation()
Dim i As Integer
With Application.FileSearch
.NewSearch
.LookIn = "C:\MyFolder\MySubFolder"
.SearchSubFolders = False
.FileName = "*.xls"
.Execute
For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
'Open each workbook
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=.FoundFiles(i))
'Perform the operation on the open workbook
'wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1") = Date
'Save and close the workbook
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header goes here"
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer goes here"
End With

Doc.Save
Doc.Close
'On to the next workbook
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For all of your question I answer YES! If you try anything and you need any help you could share your code for any support

Comment: Kaz Jaw please check the code....iam getting 5111 error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you provided you have tried to use old `.FileSearch` property. It used to work until MS Office 2003 but not now. Here goes code improved for you. It will open a standard file window where you can pick one or few files to process.

```
Sub openAllfilesInALocation()
Dim Doc
Dim i As Integer

Dim docToOpen As FileDialog
Set docToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    docToOpen.Show

For i = 1 To docToOpen.SelectedItems.Count
'Open each document
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docToOpen.SelectedItems(i))

With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header goes here"
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer goes here"
End With

Doc.Save
Doc.Close

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: For people finding this on Google, MSDN's article on modifying/accessing Headers & Footers is a good suppliment to this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194253(v=office.14).aspx