# How to open a document with VBA on a Mac?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I'm trying to write a Macro to batch process a bunch of Word docs. I need to set the page size to "Legal" for more than 200 files. The code I've written is pretty simple and seems like it should work, but I can't get the Documents.Open command to execute successfully. Every time I get this result:

> Run-time error '5174': This file could not be found.

(et cetera)  -- even when I hard-code the filename. The file definitely does exist. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Public Sub MassFormatLegal()

    Dim vDirPath As String
    Dim vFile As String
    Dim vFileName As String
    Dim oDoc As Document

    vDirPath = "MacMiniHD:Users:atc:Documents:TEST:"
    vFile = Dir(vDirPath)

    Do While vFile <> ""

        vFileName = vDirPath & vFile
        '* display the filename to verify that it's correct
        MsgBox "vFileName: " + vFileName

        '* open file
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open("MacMiniHD:Users:atc:Documents:TEST:AAFILE.doc")

        '* I also tried the following, all resulting in the same error
        '*Set oDoc = Documents.Open(vFileName)
        '*Set oDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=vFileName)
        '*Set oDoc = Application.Documents.Open(fileName:=vDirPath & vFile)

        '* change paper size
        oDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperLegal

        '* save and close the document
        oDoc.Close wdSaveChanges

        '* get next file
        vFile = Dir

    Loop

    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

Any suggestions? I've tried a lot of different approaches and am realizing that there are serious limitations of VBScript for Mac, but surely this kind of basic file handling is possible?!?

Comment: Isn't the syntax `Documents.Open Filename:="MacMiniHD:Users:atc:Documents:TEST:AAFILE.doc"`?

Comment: @dwirony your version results in a syntax error. If I add parens there's no syntax error but I get the same runtime error as before:`Documents.Open(fileName:="MacMiniHD:Users:atc:Documents:TEST:AAFILE.doc")`

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm)

Comment: Thanks @VictorK -- definitely looks relevant. I'll read it and then update this post in case someone else runs into this same problem.

Comment: So, my project has been aborted as being more trouble than it's worth, but I post the following for future reference for anyone facing similar questions:
1) File handling with VBA is a mess. Many people seem to suggest doing the open/close with AppleScript instead and to initiate the Macro in your chosen Office app. You may find this post useful: [https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/systemsbiology/staff/dyer/software/excelvbafileopen/](Opening files in Excel VBA on a mac)

Comment: And 2) The Page Size tools in MS Word are buggy. If you change the document size via the doc "Layout" menu, it will appear to have worked until you try to print the document, at which point you'll see that the paper size is still set to the old setting. You must set/confirm the size change via either the Format or File menu in order to successfully convert a document from, say A4 to US Legal. Attempting to control the size via the PageSetup property in a VBA macro also fails.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535413/filedialog-in-word-2011-vba